# How to set variable only on first launch of activity

Tags: java, android, api, android-intent

Ive got a problem. Theres a String languages and I have MainActivity(A) and ChooseLanguageActivity(B). From A user goes to B to choose language after that he intented to A  and languages get value from intent. I need to set default value for this variable languages. I tried to use it in onCreate. But I don't need use default value each time activity created. I need to use it only when app launching after that this variable need to use the value which it get from activity B intent. 
Thats code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppCompatButton chooseLanguageButton;
    AppCompatButton cleanButton;
    AppCompatEditText translatedTextOutput;
    AppCompatEditText translatedTextInput;
    String translatedInputString;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    final String TAG = "myTag";
    String language;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Timer timer;

    private TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (translatedTextInput.getText().length() != 0){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                                sendJsonRequest();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                     InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                     in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(translatedTextInput.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
            }, 600);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        language = "en";

        chooseLanguageButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.choose_language_button);
        cleanButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.clean_button);
        translatedTextOutput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translated_text_field);
        translatedTextInput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translation_input_edit);
        translatedTextInput.addTextChangedListener(searchTextWatcher);

        chooseLanguageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveText();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLanguageList.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        cleanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                translatedTextInput.setText("");
                translatedTextOutput.setText("");
            }
        });

        loadText();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        sPref = null;
    }

    void saveText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, translatedTextInput.getText().toString());
        ed.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void loadText() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        translatedTextInput.setText(savedText);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void sendJsonRequest() {
        Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        language = myIntent.getStringExtra("short");
        Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "language short = " + language);
        translatedInputString = translatedTextInput.getText().toString().replace(" ","+");
        String url = String.format(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.request_template),
                String.format(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.query_Template), translatedInputString, language ));
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Inside OnResponse" + response.toString());
                JSONArray results = null;
                try {
                    results = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations");
                    for (int i=0,j=results.length();i<j;i++) {
                        String webTitle = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("translatedText");
                        translatedTextOutput.setText(webTitle);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error :" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "NetworkError");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailureError");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!");
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "NoConnectionError!");
                } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.");
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }

}
```

P.S.Hmmm i don't understand that -1. If you make -1 at least write in comment whats wrong with question not to duplicate this mistakes next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Save boolean activityWasLauched on [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

When the app launches always put the variable as false. Inside of the onCreate of the Activity put it true, then you can use:

```
if (activityWasLauched == false){
  //use the default
}
else{
  //use a bundle and get the value from an intent
}
```

To simplify the much as possible the use of SharedPreferences:
To store values in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
if(score > high_score)
{
    editor.putInt("high_score", score);
    editor.apply();  /* Edit the value here*/
}
```

To retrieve values from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String high_score= sp.getInt("high_score", "");
```

Comment: "Save boolean activityWasLauched on SharedPreferences" Better yet, save the original variable directly to SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that variables are stored in memory and are destroyed whenever your app stops running. To store a value more permanently, you need to save it to disk. For simple values, `SharedPreferences` is the way to go. You should load the value of `languages` from `SharedPreferences` when your app starts. If no such value exists, save a default value so that the next time your app starts, it just reads the value. If something in the app changes the value of this variable, such as a user action, be sure to save the new value so that it is correct the next time your app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood you right..

**First:**

Launch your "ChooseLanguageList" activity using startActivityForResult()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLanguageList.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, ANY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**Second:**

In your "ChooseLanguageList" after setting your language return result to "MainActivity" using set result

```
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(MY_LANG_EXTRA, language);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
```

**Third:**

Back to "MainActivity".. catch the returned result using onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == ANY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    language = data.getStringExtra(MY_LANG_EXTRA);
    /* Save language in Shared Preferences */
}
```

**Fourth:**

Save your retrieved language in a Shared preference

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt(/*Key:*/"my_lang", /*value:*/language);
editor.apply();
```

**Fifth:**

Now every time you want to use language (eg. in onCreate()), just retrieve it from Shared Preferences, stating a default value in case it wasn't found

```
String language = sp.getString(/*Key:*/"my_lang", "en/*Default value*/");
```

Now each time "MainActivity" launches it will try to get language from Shared Prefs with key "my_lang", but if there is nothing there it will fall back to the default "en" until a new value is retrieved from "ChooseLanguageList" activity.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: thank you. But the question is how to set value of variable which will be used only ONE time when user just downloaded it from play market and he didn't put anything in preferences yet?